Connection threading: one thread per connection or one thread for a chunk of the IPs range?
I have no way of benchmarking at the moment, which is why I am asking. Furthermore, I would appreciate any insights on the pros and cons you might think of.
I essentially need to connect to a server with a known port (5555), but I do not know the server's hostname or IP address. I only know that the server is located on the local network with a subnet mask /24.
Since the range is 0-255, I will attempt to connect to all IP addresses in that range.
However, I need the fastest approach possible, which leads me to ask:
Should I create one thread per connection (with a cap on the maximum number of concurrent threads), or should I use a few threads to handle each chunk of the range (e.g., 0-30, 31-60, 61-90, etc.)?
Please note that I am not considering memory consumption, as I believe it would be irrelevant in this scenario.
The code will run on Android device, in case there are restrictions that I am unaware of please let me know.

You shouldn't do that at all, what you're attempting looks like a hacking attempt.  Connecting to random machines and checking to see if they happen to have a service running.  The normal way to do this is to have the user enter an IP or hostname in settings, and connect to that.

... or implement a bona fide discovery protocol.  For instance, the client might send a broadcast to its subnet, with the expectation that the server, if any, on that subnet will respond with a self-identification.  Of course, that does require the server to cooperate.

@GabeSechan it's not an hacking attempt. It was indeed to avoid entering manually the server IP from the user end.

@JohnBollinger interesting! How exactly would work something like this?

@zaxunobi, I already gave an overview in my comment.  There are many ways that the details could be arranged.

@zaxunobi I'll give youthe benefit of the doubt that you're not attempting to hack, but your behavior would be indistinguishable from a ports scanning attempt

@JohnBollinger could I use the same port I use for the TCP connection?
Discovery via UDP, Connection via TCP.

Yes, @zaxunobi, you could.  TCP and UDP use the same port number range, but the two protocols do not conflict over port numbers.  If you like, you can think of it as port numbers being namespaced by transport protocol.

@JohnBollinger silly question: are we sure that using a discovery protocol to find the server ip address and then connect, it's actually faster than trying to connect to all IPs in a subnet using multithreading? For a /24, that is.

@zaxunobi, the point is not to be faster, but rather to avoid being mistaken for a malicious actor.  However, I do expect a discovery protocol to be faster in the event that there is, in fact, a server to be discovered, because the end point for your multi-threaded approach is not that a connection is successfully made, but rather that all of the other attempts fail.
